# How to get the best number format string?

Tags: c#, .net

I read a lot of articles about number format string, ex: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

I really not understand how to write the best format string. To get a excepted result, I can write some ways. Example: print number 1234567890 as a text "1,234,567,890". These ways give the same result:

```
1234567890.ToString("#,#")
1234567890.ToString("#,##")
```

"#,##" is the popular one on internet but why? Please give me some information how to write a good format string. Thanks.

Comment: Formatting a string depends on why it needs to be formatted. Do you want to format it for currency ? If you want to format for currency you can use `1234567890.ToString("C2")` or `1234567890.ToString("c")`

Comment: When wanting to format number 1234567890 as a string "1,234,567,890", many users will think to use "#,##", but why we don't use "#,#". This is my question.

Comment: I see, so basically, *what's the difference between # and ##*. Interesting, I want to know too.

Comment: @LuLu because they won't yield the same result try using a percentage for example `double percent = .086;` with `#.#` you will get 0,1 while with `#,##` you will get 0,09

Comment: @Prix: I use common, not decimal point. Decimal point is too clear to understand.

Comment: @LuLu the separator will depend on your localization but it clearly shows the difference when using 1 place holder and 2 after the separator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see, there is no difference between `"#,#"` and `"#,##"`: both mean 'format a number with group separators and without the fractional part'. Refer to [SSCLI source for general number formatting](https://github.com/gbarnett/shared-source-cli-2.0/blob/d63349c09c2e93e4bfc4c8b147ff0805f36cec68/clr/src/vm/comnumber.cpp#L1457) for the gory details.

Comment: I notice that "#,#" "#,##" "#,###" ... give a same result. But why "#,##" more popular than others. In all ways, which way renders quickly?

Comment: Yes, they are all the same. There will be no appreciable difference in running time (see the source) but `#,#` is one less character to parse in the format string — if you are inclined to dicker for pennies when buying a house.

Comment: Why is `#,##` more popular — sheer accident plus copy-paste coding.

Answer (score 0):

In your case it does not matter, because you are using `int`. This format `#,##` and `#,#` are for doubles and means that print only two digits after decimal point

Comment: Erm, no. the comma is a group separator, not a decimal point.

Comment: You can give an example to find the difference between 2 format strings I gave. Thanks.

Comment: you are right, it depends on regional settings. If , group separator, then #,# and #,## are the same thing. If , is the decimal separator it makes a difference in the number of decimals shown

Comment: @PaoloFalabella It's a number format. If the behaviour of a number format changed depending on the region you're in, then it would be chaos, don't you think?

Comment: @Nolonar I checked with `(1234.5678).ToString("#,##",new CultureInfo("de-DE"))`, you're right.